# Contar el numero de repeticiones MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Tengo una aplicacion NodeJS con MongoDb y necesito contar el numero de usuarios agrupados por Pais. no tengo mucha experiencia en MongoDB pero lo que he conseguido con la siguiente query es agrupar los usuarios pero no realiza la cuenta correctamente:

```
async.waterfall(
        [
          (callback: any) => {
            CommunityUser.find({ community }, callback).populate("user");
          },
          (communityUser: { map: (arg0: (elem: any) => any) => void; }, callback: any) => {
            User.find({ _id: { $in: communityUser.map((elem) => elem.user) }}, callback);
          },
          (user: { map: (arg0: (elem: any) => any) => void; }, callback: any) => {
            Country.aggregate([
              {
                $match:
                  { _id: { $in: user.map((elem) => elem.profile.country) } }
              },
              { $group: { _id: { _id: "$_id", name: "$name", totalCount: { $sum: 1 } } } }], callback);
          },
        ],
```

En CommunityUser tengo el id de una comunidad y el id de un usuario. Realizo la busqueda por Comunidad y despues busco aquellos usuarios que coincide con el id del modelo CommunityUser.
Despues realizo la busqueda en Paises para obtener su id y nombre de aquellos paises que aparecen en el perfil de cada usuario y los agrupo.
Eso es lo que intento pero no se si es la manera correcta. 
El resultado obtenido es este:

```
"mostActiveUsersByCountry": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "_id": "5dc910d36eed1b2a34900f69",
                "name": "Afghanistan",
                "totalCount": 1
            }
        }
    ],
```

Es correcto. Tengo 3 usuarios de prueba todos con el mismo pais pero en totalCount deberia aparecer 3...

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema lo tienes en el `$group`, ya que estas agrupando en base a los tres campos `_id, name, totalCount`, por eso siempre te dará 1, ya que solo habrá uno que tenga los tres campos iguales.

Prueba con esta query:

```
CommunityUser.aggregate([
   {$match:{community:community}},
   {$lookup:{
       from:'user', //Nombre de la collecion a unirse
       localField:'$user', //Campo de la colección Comunity para unir
       foreignField:'$_id',  //Campo de la colección User para unir
       as:'user' // Nombre del campo al cual se añadirá los documentos relacionados
       }
    }, //join de la collection user
   {$unwind:{path:'$user', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:false}, //Eliminamos los objecto que no tienen relación con User
   {$lookup:{from:'country',localField:'$_id',foreignField:'$user.profile.country', as:'country'}}, //Join con la colección Country
   {$unwind:{path:'$country', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:false},//Eliminamos los objecto que no tienen relación con Country
   {$group:{
      _id: '$country._id', // Identificador unico, agrupamos por el _id del pais
      users: {$push:'$$ROOT.user'}, // En un campo users, añadimos los usuarios que tenga el mismo pais, solo es para que veas si son correcto al probarla.
      name: {$first: '$country.name'} // El nombre del pais
      totalCount:{$sum:1} // Sumatorio de la agrupación
 ])
```

No estoy seguro que funcione ya que no puedo saber como son los Schemas de tus colecciones, por lo que es posible que algún campo este mal nombrado.

Si no funcionara avísanos para ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, recuerda que [es.so] no es un foro. Es un sitio de `Q&A's`, como se puede leer en [Los valores fundamentales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values): *Stack Overflow es una biblioteca de soluciones preparadas y listas representadas en forma de problema (pregunta) y soluciones (respuestas), de la forma más pura y con el menor ruido posible.*  ;)